# Python Code not Performing as expected

Tags: python, performance, numpy

whey would this piece of Python code execute 2.5 times slower than the second version?

```
backTrack = np.zeros((len(v)+1, len(w)+1), dtype = int)
s = np.zeros((len(v)+1, len(w)+1), dtype = int)

# Fill in the 's' matrix.
for i in range(1, len(v)+1):
    for j in range(1, len(w)+1):
        scores = [s[i-1, j] - sigma, s[i, j-1] - sigma, s[i-1, j-1] + [-1, 1][v[i-1] == w[j-1]]]
        s[i, j] = max(scores)
        backTrack[i, j] = scores.index(s[i, j])
```

Second bit:

```
S = [[0 for j in range(len(w)+1)] for i in range(len(v)+1)]
backtrack = [[0 for j in range(len(w)+1)] for i in range(len(v)+1)]
# Fill in the Score and Backtrack matrices.
iterations = 0
for i in range(1, len(v)+1):
    for j in range(1, len(w)+1):
        scores = [S[i-1][j] - sigma, S[i][j-1] - sigma, S[i-1][j-1] + [-1, 1][v[i-1] == w[j-1]]]
        S[i][j] = max(scores)
        backtrack[i][j] = scores.index(S[i][j])
```

The only difference is that in the first version, the arrays are declared via numpy, and in the second, they're just Python lists of lists.

This is a string alignment bit of code for those interested.  Also, len(v) and len(w) are just less than 10,000, so that loop goes around about 85 million times.

I've tried different datatypes with the numpy arrays (e.g. int32, int64, float), but to no avail.

Comment: Oh this is on Windows 8.1.

Comment: The first code is slower because it takes time to extract a number from a numpy array, and turn it into a Python object. When working with numpy, you must never loop over members of large arrays by hand. Instead, try to find a numpy primitive to do the memberwise operations for you. For example, instead of summing arrays member by member, just use `array1 + array2`.

Comment: @user4815162342, this is only half of the truth. `You must never loop` should be replaced by `you should try to avoid`. However often there is no easy way to express certain algorithms in a vectorized form. (This is especially true for algorithms filling a dynamic programming matrix). Usually the way here is to get to a statically typed code, `cython` e.g. is a straightforward way to speed loops up.

Comment: Ok, so is it to do with memory slowness when iterating over a large array?  Memory being swapped in/out etc?

But if that's the case, why is the Python array (list of lists) faster?  Surely this would have the same memory access problems?

Comment: @davo36, no the problem is, as @user4815162342 said, that in python all `primitive` types such as `int` and `float` are actually python objects. This is the price you have to pay for the convenience of having dynamic typing. `numpy` functions on whole arrays use statical typing. Therefore no objects are created and an `int`, is really just a `int`, not a whole `object`. This of course only works, because `numpy` arrays have a fixed type. So you will get a speed up by statically typing, but not by using a different representation of your data.

Comment: @cel I think we are in agreement here - my "must never loop" warning referred to loops written in pure interpreted Python. Looping in C (or Cython) is OK because not only is the loop overhead smaller, but one avoids the cost of boxing and unboxing the primitive values.

Comment: Loops are common in pure Python.  That's how you traverse a list.  It's in `numpy`, with a rich set of compiled iterative operations, where the 'never loop' dictum is most applicable.  But even there 'no loops' is a goal, not a rule.

Comment: But none of this explains why the numpy code is SLOWER by 2.5 times.  In fact the above comments seem to be suggesting that the Python code should be the slower code since it's using object, not just ints.  So to repeat, the slower code in my example above is the numpy code, the all Python code runs faster which I just don't understand.